# WCF RIA Services, Joining Tables in Domain Service

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I'm making a Silverlight WCF RIA Services application. Although, I'm stuck attempting different ways to use multiple Tables in the database. 
Currently, I'm trying to join tables in the Domain Service Class and return it to the service agent. I started this project from a template located at:
http://simplemvvmtoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20RIA%20Services

I'm trying to join tables like:

```
    public IQueryable<Invoice> GetInvoices()
    {
        return (from i in this.ObjectContext.Invoices 
                join o in this.ObjectContext.otherTable equals condition 
                join s in this.ObjectContext.otherTable equals condition 
                select i); 
    }
```

This joins the tables correctly based on the given conditions. But I actually need to Project Fields from both the i.Invoices Tables & s.otherTable.
Any suggestions to make this projection work in the DomainServiceClass.cs ?

SAMPLE CODE FROM USER "Chris" Suggestion:

```
    public class Invoice_PM
    {
    [Key]
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }

    public string PaymentNum { get; set; }

    public DateTime? PaymentExpDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime? InvoiceDateTime { get; set; }

    [Include, Association("name", "InvoiceID", "InvoiceDateTime")]
    public IEnumerable<InvoiceSoldToShipTo_PM> SoldToShipTo { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your LINQ query is only using the joins to basically filter the Invoices since you are selecting the i variable at the end.  I think the answer to this post will get you you the result you want:

[Error: The entity or complex type cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215354/error-the-entity-or-complex-type-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-qu)

I suggest you create a custom class with all of the properties that you want to load and select the results of your LINQ statement into your custom class.

Custom Class:

```
public class CustomInvoice
{
    public int InvoiceID { get; set; }
    public int InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int InvoiceID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}
```

Domain Service Function:

```
public IQueryable<CustomInvoice> GetInvoices() 
{ 
    return (from i in this.ObjectContext.Invoices  
            join p in this.ObjectContext.Product equals condition  
            join c in this.ObjectContext.Customer equals condition  
            select new CustomInvoice
            { 
                InvoiceID = i.ID, 
                InvoideNumber = i.InvoiceNumber, 
                ProductID = p.ID, 
                ProductName = p.Name, 
                CustomerID = c.ID, 
                CustomerName = c.Name
            }; );  
}
```

I haven't tried tested this code, but the idea should get you there.

Comment: When I try that, there is a build error that comes back. "Inconsistent accessibility: return type" I believe it's because of the Generated Domain Service Method's that are related to the GetInvoices() method. So then how can I apply those updates, delete, and insert functions?

Comment: Link to the Compile Error: http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(CS0050);k(VS.ERRORLIST)&rd=true

Comment: Don't use the generated method to return a collection of your new type, set the generated method back to what it originally was with a return type of IQueryable<Invoice> and then create a new method manually called something like GetCustomInvoices with the return type of IQueryable<CustomInvoice>.  I think this should fix your problem since I have custom methods in my domain service that return custom types.

Comment: Thanks, Now I'm recieving this error(I've updated my Post): "Error: Association named xxx defined on entity type" I read up on it at http://forums.silverlight.net/p/140634/628712.aspx/1?Re+Error+Association+named+xxx+defined+on+entity+type

Comment: I should probably ask what you are intending to do with this custom object. Do you need this object only to store data from your custom query, or do you actually want to use this class as a Domain Services object and be able to make changes to the data through this object and be able to submit changes to the database via a context.SubmitChanges() call? If you want to just store data in this object for displaying it in your application, you are almost there. If you want to be able to update/save changes via this object to the databse, this is not the way to go.

Comment: Thank you Chris for the help.